# PyQt for spyder 2.2.0 python 2.7 installation

Tags: python-2.7, pyqt4, spyder

I used the windows installer executable to install pyQt4, but i can't seem to import PyQt4 in my console window (command window).

I run the command "import pyqt4" and get the error "ImportError: No module named pyqt4"

I was able to run the above command for pyodbc and panda with no problems after installing them using their respective windows installers.

any clues??

sorry if i'm missing something obvious - i'm a beginner here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The module's name is case sensitive, so instead of

```
import pyqt4
```

you need to write

```
import PyQt4
```

Comment: By the way, you can use the `tab` key to get code completions on the Spyder console after writing `import`. This way you can easily inspect the right name you need to use on every module.